# Заменить старое значение на новое node js json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Имеется json файл
Name:artur
Age:60
Как мне в этом файле заменить имя артур на условно олег? Что бы Age остался.

Comment: Прочитать файл. Распарсить JSON. Заменить значение в полученном объекте. Сериализовать JSON. Записать в файл. В чём именно у вас трудность?